# SQL Server View runs fine in Access, but form subtotals are extremely slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ms-access

I have an Access database with several links to SQL Server Views. These Views serve as record sources for various continuous forms. They all open in less than a second. But as soon as I add a subtotal to any of the form footers, everything freezes.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT dbo.[budget entries].budgetentryid,
       dbo.[budget entries].fund,
       dbo.[budget entries].department,
       dbo.[budget entries].object,
       dbo.[budget entries].subcode,
       dbo.[budget entries].trackingcode,
       dbo.[budget entries].reserve,
       dbo.[budget entries].amount,
       dbo.[budget entries].description,
       dbo.[budget entries].entrymethod,
       dbo.[budget entries].approvalstatus,
       dbo.[budget entries].timestamp,
       dbo.[budget entries].userstamp,
       dbo.[budget entries].selected,
       dbo.[budget entries].fyend,
       dbo.[budget entries].importid,
       dbo.[budget entries].allocationschemeid,
       dbo.[budget entries].allocationentryid,
       dbo.[budget entries].personid,
       dbo.[budget entries].locationid,
       dbo.[budget entries].compositeid
FROM   dbo.[budget entries]
       INNER JOIN dbo.vwcurrentuser
               ON dbo.[budget entries].fyend = dbo.vwcurrentuser.currentfye
       INNER JOIN dbo.vwavailablefunds
               ON dbo.[budget entries].fund = dbo.vwavailablefunds.fund
```

The view is called vwBudgetEntries. Basically, it grabs the username in order to filter the budget year and funds. It returns all the budget entries relevant to the current user. I have a form which uses vwBudgetEntries as the record source. It opens in less than a second. But when I modify the form to sum the amount field (using `=Sum(Nz([Amount],0))`), it suddenly takes 1-2 minutes to navigate between records.

Weirdly, when I recreate the view as a local query, the subtotal works fine and doesn't freeze anything up. Can anyone explain to me why this happens? For reasons I won't get into, I'd prefer linked views or pass-through queries over local queries.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/acc-you-may-encounter-slow-performance-or-hangs-when-designing-executing-queries-that-include-pass-through-queries-01e1d72e-d214-6daa-db52-89e2dd837177

Comment: This is for pass-through queries. I'm currently using linked views, which is what they recommend. They also recommend using Snapshot instead of Dynaset, but I tried it, and it didn't help.

Comment: Not sure if this has bearing, but keep in mind that Access is Client-Side.  This means, everything you do with the data needs to be pulled through the pipe and calculated on the client side.  I'm not positive if a form sum requires the data to be pulled through the pipe once for every record you're summing, but that would explain why a local query returns the data faster.

Comment: Maybe. It looks like I can avoid the issue by using domain aggregate functions, instead of summing each control. It takes a few seconds instead of a few minutes, although it's not as fast as the local query. More importantly, however, it lets me navigate between records while it's calculating.

Comment: Start by trying to remove the `Nz`. This isn't needed, and `Nz` in Access is a strange function (it's not a standard VBA or SQL function, but an Access application-level function, which means it commonly causes slowdowns and queries using it are unavailable through DAO or ODBC). I generally avoid `Nz` and use `IIF(SomeField Is Null, 0, SomeField)` instead which is a default function and thus available externally and the optimizer is much better at handling it. But here, it's entirely unneeded as Access excludes NULL in a sum by default

Answer (score 0):

I think @Johnny_Bones was onto something, although I couldn't find any official info to back it up. The solution I settled on was to pass the form filter into `DSum`. That way it stays relevant to the user's filter selections, but it only has to pull the data through once. It's not perfect, but it's much faster and doesn't cause hanging.